# PostgreSQL DELETE FROM (SELECT * FROM table FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY)

Tags: postgresql, subquery, sql-delete

How do I delete only a few rows in postgreSQL?
I want to fetch 10 rows to delete in a subquery.

My table

[image]

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You need to use a where condition as per your requirement like this:

```
delete from mytable where id in(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

or

```
delete from mytable where id in(select id from mytable where someconditon)
```

or you can try like this if you want to delete top 10 using [ctid](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-system-columns.html):

```
DELETE FROM mytable 
WHERE ctid IN (
    SELECT ctid
    FROM mytable 
    GROUP BY s.serialId, s.valuetimestamp
    ORDER BY s.serialId
    LIMIT 10
)
```

If you are looking to remove the duplicates from your table then try this:

```
DELETE FROM mytable
 WHERE ctid NOT IN
  (SELECT MAX(s.ctid)
    FROM table s
    GROUP BY s.serialId, s.valuetimestamp);
```

Comment: I only have the same SerialId and valuetimestamp´s. Se my picture that I added.

Comment: @ArthurDatur:- You want to remove the duplicates?

Comment: No, I want to remove half of the posts LIMIT 10 (of 20) bu in the reality it´s thousands of rows There are no duplicates

Comment: @ArthurDatur:- Please see my edit. I have update my answer.

Comment: I didnt know about CTID! that works fine! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you have some unique identifier (serial, let's call it "id") in your table, then just make something like :

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE table.id IN (SELECT table.id FROM table WHERE *whatever*)
```

Add or not something like "LIMIT 0,10"

Comment: I only have the same SerialId and valuetimestamp´s. Please se my screendump that I added